# Tracking all logins through the membershipprovider / forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I'm using the default `SqlMembershipProvider` and like to track all logins. The login with username/password is no problem since they goes through the `AccountController`.

But how do I track the logins which are made using the membership cookie?